# laravel date time to date from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

the date stored in mysql is in Datetime format **'Y-m-d H:m:s'** using laravel eloquent I want to convert Datetime format to date **'Y-m-d'**
the date stored in mysql table is **2016-11-29 17:23:56** and in the controller to convert I am using the below

**$currentdate = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:m:s",$token->IssueDate)->format("Y-m-d");**

the result I am getting is  **"2017-11-29"**
another example

Mysql record stored date is **2016-12-01 17:27:47** and the result I am getting is **"2018-03-01"**

Please help what am I missing here.

I have a constructor in the controller

```
public function  __construct()
{
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
}
```

which I don't think is a pronblem as after removing I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`m` is month. You want `i` for minutes ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)):

```
$currentdate = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$token->IssueDate)->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Y-m-d H:m:s` to `Y-m-d H:i:s` (`i` refers to minute, not `m`). More on [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).